# Spring Boot POST request to endpoint returning Null values

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I am sending the request payload from post man. I want some other fields in the entity to store null value until another action is performed (Activate) but for other fields that I send their values , I get a Null response and for other fields that values set returns 0.0

This is the model

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Investment 

   {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "AccountNumber", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int accountNumber;
    private String category;
    private BigDecimal principal;
    //private BigDecimal netInvestmentAmount;
    private BigDecimal currentInterest;
    private BigDecimal maturityInterest;
    private String tenure;
    private String marketer;
    private String investmentPackage;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate startDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate maturityDate;
    private int rate;
    private final float wht = 10/100;
    private String whtStatus;
    private final float  preLiquidationCharges = 25/100;
    @Enumerated(EnumType .STRING)
    private InvestmentStatus status;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class, 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_fk_id") 
    private Customer customer_id ;
```

This is the service class containing the business logic for creating investment.

```
public Investment CreateInvestment(Investment investment)
       {
        investment.setAccountNumber(nextAccountNumber());
        investment.setStatus(InvestmentStatus.pending);
         return investmentRepository.save(investment);
      }
```

This is the controller class code ,

```
 @PostMapping(value="/createInvestment")
    public @ResponseBody Investment CreateInvestment (Investment investment)  
    {
     investmentService.CreateInvestment(investment);
     return investment;
    }
```

This is the request payload on postman send to the endpoint to create investment account.

```
    {
        "category": "Corporafe",
        "principal":65000,
        "tenure": "30",
        "investmentPackage": "Premium Investment",
        "rate": 12,
        "whtStatus": "Yes",
         "customer" : {"id": 14}
       }
```

This is the response payload gotten after making a post request to the endpoint

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "accountNumber": 2021070417,
    "category": null,
    "principal": null,
    "currentInterest": null,
    "maturityInterest": null,
    "tenure": null,
    "marketer": null,
    "investmentPackage": null,
    "startDate": null,
    "maturityDate": null,
    "rate": 0,
    "wht": 0.0,
    "whtStatus": null,
    "preLiquidationCharges": 0.0,
    "status": "pending",
    "customer": null
}
```

**Updated**: this is the repository class

```
@Repository
public interface InvestmentRepository extends JpaRepository <Investment, Long>

 {
    
    Optional<Investment> findById(Long id);
    
    List<Investment> findByStartDateBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
    
    
    @Query("SELECT new com.bethsaida.org.models.InvestmentDTO (c.firstName, c.lastName, c.Address, c.category, c.marketer, "
            + "i.accountNumber, i.principal, i.maturityInterest, i.startDate, i.maturityDate, i.status, i.tenure)"
            + " FROM Investment i JOIN i.customer_id c")
    List<InvestmentDTO> getJoinInformation(Long id);
```

**Update** I added @RequestBody to the post request arguments . Now the selected fields are being populated but the Customer details response displays null for all fields .

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "accountNumber": 2021070417,
    "category": "Individual",
    "principal": 50000,
    "currentInterest": null,
    "maturityInterest": null,
    "tenure": "30",
    "marketer": null,
    "investmentPackage": "Classic Investment",
    "startDate": null,
    "maturityDate": null,
    "rate": 12,
    "wht": 0.1,
    "whtStatus": "Yes",
    "preLiquidationCharges": 0.25,
    "status": "pending",
    "customer": {
        "id": 13,
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "gender": null,
        "maritalStatus": null,
        "category": null,
        "motherMaidenName": null,
        "idType": null,
        "idNumber": null,
        "marketer": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "email": null,
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "registrationDate": null,
        "address": null
    }
}
```

Comment: The controller method should probably `return investmentService.CreateInvestment(investment)`.

Comment: @AndrewS I changed the controller return method but it is still returning null values.

Comment: It looks like `accountNumber` and `status` are being set.  Also 10/100 and 25/100 is integer division which will result in 0.  What does 'investmentRepository' do?

Comment: @AndrewS yes accountNumber and status are being set . Thanks for the integer division notification . I have updated the the post to include the Repository class .

Answer (score 2):

Ok i fixed this by adding @RequestBody to the controller Method , then Changed CascadeType.ALL to CascadeType.MERGE in the Investment Class where FetchType Lazy is being used.